# Optimizing a function that traverses a graph with no cycles

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, graph

Given a large dataframe, i need to match each child position with each parent position, following these rules:

- every chile has, at least, one parent
- multiple children can have the same parent
- the final parent should be found in a given list, so that, each child found in the chain, that shares the same parent will have the final parent's ID (that will be used for further operations)
- if there is a final parent that is not in the given list, the final parent will become the previous parent, until the first parent is part of the list.

the initial dataframe might look like this:

```
| Name | ChildPosition | ParentPosition |
|------|---------------|----------------|
| AAA  |    39602320   |     10092002   |
| BBB  |    10092002   |     50002102   |
| CCC  |    10131807   |     10109077   |
| DDD  |    10062441   |     39602320   |
| EEE  |    39602320   |     39600136   |
| FFF  |    39600136   |     10092002   |
```

and the given list:

```
Name | Position | ID
VVV  | 50002102 |689
TTT  | 10092002 |731
```

According with this example, AAA and BBB should have the same parent VVV, both being allocated the ID 689.

Until now, i have this function:

```py
def walk(df, id, f, r, prev=pd.Series(dtype="int64")):
"""
    Recursively traverse a DataFrame to retrieve a chain of values based on specified conditions.

    Parameters:
        df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame to traverse.
        id: The starting identifier for the traversal.
        f (str): The column name used to filter rows in the DataFrame.
        r (str): The column name whose values are collected during traversal.
        prev (pd.Series, optional): A series used to accumulate values during recursion.

    Returns:
        pd.Series: A series containing values collected during traversal.
   """
    mgr = df.loc[df[f] == id,][r]
    if not mgr.isna().all():
        prev = walk(df, mgr.tolist()[0], f, r, prev)
    return pd.concat([mgr, prev])
```

This traverses the dataframe, retrieving a chain of values based on the relation child-parent, returning the final parent position and all the children, for each parent.

And it's being used like this:

```
df = df.assign(
        mgrs=lambda x: x["ChildPosition"].apply(
            lambda e: (
                walk(x, e, "ChildPosition", "ParentCode")
                .dropna()
                .astype("int64")
                .tolist()
            )
        ),
        emps=lambda x: x["ChildPosition"].apply(
            lambda e: (
                walk(x, e, "ParentCode", "ChildPosition")
                .dropna()
                .astype("int64")
                .tolist()
            )
        ),
    )
```

The problem is that this method takes too long (83 seconds) and will be called several times, the final time reaching hours (theoretical), which is too long.

How can this be optimized, in order to shorten the execution time?

Example of an expected output, from the real dataframe, where the children are the IDs present, that have associated names and other characteristics, and parents are a list of children ID's found as positions, that have other parents. So on and so forth, until the last one. As an idea, the child 39602320 has the first parent 39600136, which has the child postion 39600136 with 10092002 as a parent, etc.:

| Children | Parents |
| --- | --- |
| 39602320 | [39600136, 39600136, 10092002, 10092002, 10102028, 39604655, 50008982, 10074224, 10074224, 50002171, 10134484, 50002102, 50002102] |
| 10131807 | [10109077, 10109077, 10070230, 10070230, 10073971, 10073971, 10133209, 10133209, 68505160, 68505160, 10074224, 10074224, 50002171, 10134484, 50002102, 50002102] |
| 10062441 | [39602320, 39602320, 39600136, 39600136, 10092002, 10092002, 10102028, 39604655, 50008982, 10074224, 10074224, 50002171, 10134484, 50002102, 50002102] |
| 10052497 | [10109077, 10109077, 10070230, 10070230, 10073971, 10073971, 10133209, 10133209, 68505160, 68505160, 10074224, 10074224, 50002171, 10134484, 50002102, 50002102] |
| 10112867 | [10130906, 10130906, 68017568, 68017568, 68502208, 68502208, 10091176, 10091176, 10135119, 10135119, 68505303, 68505303, 10134484, 10134484, 50002171, 50002171, 50002102, 50002102] |

The above extraction takes into consideration the whole dataframe, so if in the example, you won't find some of the position, it's because they appear lower on the dataframe. The duplicated entries represent the entries for a month and should be there.

So that the parents column could be extracted, reversed and matched with the other list

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Added in the question's body, for clarity. i will add some other functions that help in this situation if needed

Comment: Please don't provide an random example of output, but the exact expected output given the provided example input. Make the example input slightly more complex if this better illustrates what you want but keep it within a reasonable length (<10 rows).

Comment: Also explain how exactly you are using your current function, the parameters are too cryptic to guess.

Comment: i've tried to clarify as many details as i could, so that this problem can be understood better. I hope it's all clear now. I will add more things in the future, if needed. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Please take the comments into consideration. The output should relate to the example input.

Comment: Make an actual graph with something like `networkx`